# Sphinx : mix revelance and age for sorting

Tags: sphinx, relevance

In my index I've  2 textfield: title & content, and one attribute date_publish.

I want  order by

title relevance, publication age, content relevance

With Sphinx 2.0.2 AND **SphinxSE**

how can do it ?
search mode -> expr ?
rank_mode -> expr ?

I'm lost..

actually  my idea is

bm25(@title)*1000+(1000/ (now()-date_publish)/86400) + bm25(@content)/10

(Note, all this still in limbo I would refine my question   withh your comments and results of my experiences ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can get 'relevance' factors per field as such, so cant explicitly sort like that.

But can use field weights to alter the 'per field' weight, so that title could have a greater effect than content.

You can then either use a ranking expression to factor in the 'age' of the document, similar to your example.

Or could jsut explicitly sort by relevance then sort by date - using extended sort mode.

The other way to sort by reverence, but still promote recent content to the top, is to use 'Time Segment' sorting. see SPH_SORT_TIME_SEGMENTS

Comment: currently I use  field weights  and SPH_SORT_TIME_SEGMENTS  and  the request for product owner is  give more weight if "it's in title  than publish date  like if I can write   ;fieldweights=title,40,publish_date,25,content,2

Comment: so perhaps fieldweights=title,40,content,2;rank=expr:bm25*1000+(NOW()-ressource_date)*10;  

I'm trying this solution but it's not easy to see if it's works with sphinxse

Comment: Note that just using `bm25` in the expression wont take into account field weights (its a document level factor). Perhaps see the expression for SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 to see how to factor in user_weight (ie field weights)

Comment: exact since my comment i've replace bm25  by  sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25  (found in manual : SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 = sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25  )